# Proving that a function does belong to a set

Tags: group-theory, functions, vector-spaces

Prove that the the following function:
 $$\left\{ \begin{matrix}\left( \forall x\in \mathbb{R} \right) \left( \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R} \right)/f_{\alpha }\left( x\right) =f\left( x+\alpha \right)\end{matrix} \right\}$$

Does belong to $E$: 
$$E=\{ f\in F\left( \mathbb{R} \right) |~f=a\varphi _{1}+b\varphi _{2}/ \left( a;b\right) \in \mathbb{R} ^{2} \}$$
  And: $$\begin{cases} \varphi _{1}=e^{x}\cos x\\ \varphi _{2}=e^{x}\sin x\end{cases}$$

---

$$\left( E,+,\right)$$ is a vectorial space and $$ B=\left( \varphi _{1},\varphi _{2}\right)$$ is a basis in E

Side note:$$f\in E\Rightarrow f'\in E$$